# Trying to use a method to generate a random dice number with a custom amount of sides that is input by the user

Tags: c#

I have a program that asks the user how many dice they want to roll and then rolls them. Each dice has 6 sides so only possible outcomes are 1-6. Currently everything is working as it should but I would like to make the user have to input the amount of sides the dice have, so instead of the random function being .Next(1, 7);, it would be .Next(1, amountSides); where amountSides stands for the amount of sides the dice have. I have managed to do it without using a method but my professor wants me to use one, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static int RollDice(Random randomObject, int amountSides)
        {
            amountSides = 0;
            int random = randomObject.Next(1, amountSides);
            return random;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Random random = new Random(); slumptal
            List<int> dices = new List<int>();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\tWelcome to the dice generator!");

            bool run = true;
            while (run)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t[1] Roll dice\n" +
                    "\t[2] Check what you rolled\n" +
                    "\t[3] Quit");
                Console.Write("\tChoose: ");
                int choice;
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice);
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("\n\tHow many dices do you want to roll: ");
                        bool input = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int amount);
                        Console.Write("\n\tHow many dices do you want to roll:  ");
                        int amountSides = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                        if (input)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
                            {
                                // här kallar vi på metoden RullaTärning
                                // och sparar det returnerade värdet i 
                                // listan tärningar
                                dices.Add(RollDice(random, amountSides));
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        int sum = 0;tärningsrullningar.
                        if (dices.Count <= 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tThere are no saved dice rolls! ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tRolled dice: ");
                            foreach (int dice in dices)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\t" + dice);
                                sum += dice;
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine("\n\tAverage of rolled dices: " + sum / dices.Count);
                        }

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tThank you for rolling dice");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        run = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tChoose 1-3 from the menu");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to "transfer" the amountSides variable to the method so that it can perform the calculation and return the correct random number.

I also want to add that I have succesfully done it without using a method but as stated previously, my professor demands a method to be used for this. Here is the same thing done without using a method.

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            List<int> dices = new List<int>();

            Console.WriteLine("How many dice do you want to roll:");
            bool input = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int amount);
            Console.WriteLine("How many sides do the dices have:");
            int amountSides = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (input)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
                {
                   dices.Add(random.Next(1,amountSides));
                }
                foreach(int dice in dices)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dice);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. What is `RollDice` if not a method. What else your professor wants? "I don't know how to "transfer" the amountSides variable to the method " You are already  calling that method with that argument.

Comment: It is a method but he wants to let the user decide the amount of sides the dice have

Comment: You are already asking the user for it: `int amountSides = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `amountSides = 0;`. Don't override method parameters.

> Each dice has 6 sides so only possible outcomes are 1-6

Then you don't need a parameter, or `amountSides` at all, so there is nothing to "transfer"

```
static int RollDice(Random randomObject)
{
    return randomObject.Next(1, 7);
}
```

...

```
dices.Add(RollDice(random));
```

Otherwise, if you want other sized dice, you ask for the number of sides, (as you had already done)...

And you use that parameter (as you did), but **do not override it**

```
static int RollDice(Random randomObject, int sides)
{
    return randomObject.Next(1, sides);
}
```

...

```
Console.Write("\n\tHow many dices do you want to roll: ");
bool input = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int amount);

Console.Write("\n\tHow many sides does each die have:  ");
int amountSides = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        dices.Add(RollDice(random, amountSides));
    }
}
```

Comment: "I would like to make the user have to input the amount of sides the dice have, so instead of the random function being .Next(1, 7);, it would be .Next(1, amountSides);"

Comment: Hi! Sorry if I was unclear but I want to let the user decide how many sides the dice have like this: `static int RollDice(Random randomObject)
{
    return randomObject.Next(1, amountOfSides);
}`

Comment: @blaeck You need a parameter. See updated answer